# protobuf.encode() does not work as expected in protobufjs package

Tags: node.js, protocol-buffers

I using this package [protobufjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protobufjs).

This problem waste my time for 4 days and I don't understand why?
protobuff.verify()  has no error and all properties set as well
I'm sure files and them imports loaded as well and there is problem about it
All usage on another side of my project works without problem but at This side I have this problem

protobuf.js version: ^7.2.3

```js
        let settings = {
            port_list: {
                range: [{
                    From: 1,
                    To: 100
                }]
            },
            listen: {},
            allocation_strategy: {},
            stream_settings: {},
            receive_original_destination: {},
            sniffing_settings: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }
        let error = ReceiverSetting.verify(settings)
        let receiverSetting = ReceiverSetting.create(settings)
        console.log('error: ', error)
        const buffer = ReceiverSetting.encode(receiverSetting).finish();
        console.log('receiverSetting:', receiverSetting);
        console.log('buffer:', buffer);
        const decodedMessage = ReceiverSetting.decode(buffer);
        console.log('decodedMessage:', decodedMessage);
```

and in the log section:

```
error:  null
receiverSetting: ReceiverConfig {
  domainOverride: [],
  port_list: { range: [ [Object] ] },
  listen: {},
  allocation_strategy: {},
  stream_settings: {},
  receive_original_destination: {},
  sniffing_settings: {}
}
buffer: <Buffer 12 00>
decodedMessage: ReceiverConfig { domainOverride: [], listen: IPOrDomain {} }
```

proto file:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package xray.app.proxyman;


import "common/net/address.proto";
import "common/net/port.proto";
import "transport/internet/config.proto";
import "common/serial/typed_message.proto";

...
...
...
message ReceiverConfig {
  xray.common.net.PortList port_list = 1;
  xray.common.net.IPOrDomain listen = 2;
  AllocationStrategy allocation_strategy = 3;
  xray.transport.internet.StreamConfig stream_settings = 4;
  bool receive_original_destination = 5;
  reserved 6;
  repeated KnownProtocols domain_override = 7 [ deprecated = true ];
  SniffingConfig sniffing_settings = 8;
}
message SniffingConfig {
  // Whether or not to enable content sniffing on an inbound connection.
  bool enabled = 1;

  // Override target destination if sniff'ed protocol is in the given list.
  // Supported values are "http", "tls", "fakedns".
  repeated string destination_override = 2;
  repeated string domains_excluded = 3;

  // Whether should only try to sniff metadata without waiting for client input.
  // Can be used to support SMTP like protocol where server send the first
  // message.
  bool metadata_only = 4;

  bool route_only = 5;
}
...
...
...
...
```

Comment: Your code doesn't provide a standalone repro of your issue and this make it more difficult to help. I'm not familiar with protobufjs but...

Comment: (1) Your imports (e.g. `common/net/port.proto`) don't match your references `xray.common.net.PortList`. You should likely revise the `xray` imports to be prefixed with `xray` e.g. `import "xray/common/net/port.proto`.

Comment: (2) There's likely some name conversions between the proto e.g. `port_list` and the generated code unless you're inhibiting this e.g. `portList`

Comment: (3) It's unclear from [`protobufjs`](https://github.com/protobufjs/protobuf.js) how to construct nested messages e.g. `xray.common.net.PortList`. You do this using pure JSON but it may (!?) be that you must `new` Messages and then assemble them into JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with [`protobufjs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protobufjs).

It was unclear where you're sourcing `xray` but I used [Xray-core](https://github.com/XTLS/Xray-core) and copied the protobuf sources to my `protos` directory (as below).

I did have to change one of the Xray-core references to get the tree to compile.

Structure:

```
.
├── foo.json
├── index.js
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── protos
│   └── xray
│       ├── app
│       ├── common
│       ├── core
│       └── transport
└── README.md
```

I revised your proto so that I could compile it:
`foo.proto`:

```protobuf
syntax = "proto3";

package xray.app.proxyman;


import "xray/common/net/address.proto";
import "xray/common/net/port.proto";
import "xray/transport/internet/config.proto";
import "xray/common/serial/typed_message.proto";

message ReceiverConfig {
  xray.common.net.PortList port_list = 1;
  xray.common.net.IPOrDomain listen = 2;
//  AllocationStrategy allocation_strategy = 3;
  xray.transport.internet.StreamConfig stream_settings = 4;
  bool receive_original_destination = 5;
  reserved 6;
//  repeated KnownProtocols domain_override = 7 [ deprecated = true ];
  SniffingConfig sniffing_settings = 8;
}
message SniffingConfig {
  // Whether or not to enable content sniffing on an inbound connection.
  bool enabled = 1;

  // Override target destination if sniff'ed protocol is in the given list.
  // Supported values are "http", "tls", "fakedns".
  repeated string destination_override = 2;
  repeated string domains_excluded = 3;

  // Whether should only try to sniff metadata without waiting for client input.
  // Can be used to support SMTP like protocol where server send the first
  // message.
  bool metadata_only = 4;

  bool route_only = 5;
}
```

1. Prefixed `xray` references e.g. `xray.common.net.PortList`
2. Commented Messages that aren't defined e.g. `AllocationStrategy`

It is unclear to me how to specify `proto_path` using `protobufjs`, so I compiled to the JSON schema:

```bash
./node_modules/.bin/pbjs \
--path=${PWD}/protos \
${PWD}/protos/xray/app/proxyman/foo.proto \
> foo.json
```

Then:

`index.js`:

```
var protobuf = require("protobufjs");

protobuf.load("foo.json").then((root) => {
  console.log(root);

  const ReceiverConfig = root.lookupType("xray.app.proxyman.ReceiverConfig");

  // By introspecting foo.json schema:
  // 1. portList not port_list
  // 2. From|To initial letter uppercase
  const payload = {
            portList: {
                range: [{
                    From: 1000,
                    To: 1999,
                }],
            },
        };

  const errMsg = ReceiverConfig.verify(payload);
  if (errMsg)
    throw Error(errMsg);

  const message = ReceiverConfig.create(payload);
  console.log(`receiverSetting: ${JSON.stringify(message)}`);

  const buffer = ReceiverConfig.encode(message).finish();

  const decoded = ReceiverConfig.decode(buffer);
  console.log(`receiverSetting: ${JSON.stringify(message)}`);
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Yields:

```
receiverSetting: {"portList":{"range":[{"From":1000,"To":1999}]}}
receiverSetting: {"portList":{"range":[{"From":1000,"To":1999}]}}
```